# How to access HTML script variable in QT

Tags: javascript, html, c++, qt

I am someone who is new to QT. I am creating a HTML report page in QT.
In that I am creating a table and populating my data into it using the following:

```
htmlFile.open(path);
htmlFile<<"<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body>";
htmlFile<<"<table id='myTable'>"
          "<tr>"
         "<td>Feature</td>"
         "<td>Test Count</td>"
         "<td>PASS</td>"
         "<td>FAIL</td>"
         "<td>SKIPPED</td>"             
         "</tr>";
```

I have a script that displays the row index, column and the value of the cell.This is my script :

```
QString val;
htmlFile<<"<script  src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js'></script>"
          "<script>"
          "$(document).ready(function(){"
          "$('#myTable td').click(function() {"
          "var column_num = parseInt( $(this).index() ) + 1;"
          "var row_num = parseInt( $(this).parent().index() )+1;"
          "var txt='Row:' +row_num+' Column : '+column_num;"
          "txt+=' Value: '+ document.getElementById('myTable').rows[row_num-1].cells[column_num-1].innerHTML; "
          "alert(txt); }); });"
          "</script>";
```

Now I want the variable 'txt' to be used in my class, ie, something like val=txt (which definitely is not possible directly). Is there any way to do so? Can a global variable help me?

This is my first HTML and script attempt. So I m a bit confused. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use an xml parser so your html file can be load has object. qt provide an xml parser see http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdomdocument.html